# Disconnect cooker hood controls

Tags: switch, circuit

I have a broken plastic part, disabling the button for the light switch on my cooker hood. Now I can fix it, but I've unhooked both the light switch and the hood switch, and I can't find how to connect it again. Forgot to take pictures unfortunately... I've found this circuit online, can anyone help me out how to connect it? Brown thing is the light switch. Can provide better pictures if necessary. Thanks a million in advance!

[image: The mess]

[image: Electric circuit]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sorry, but if you can trust that diagram then it's showing something different than what your picture shows. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Please provide make and model

Comment: Whirlpool Cooker Hood 600.961.70 LUFTIG HOO C00 S